# Construction of a Frobenius algebra object

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, hopf-algebras, topological-quantum-field-theory

I am working with a rigid, abelian braided category $\mathcal{C}$, which has a natural Hopf algebra object defined via the coend $C=\int^{X \in \mathcal{C}}X^{*}\otimes X$, where $X^{*}$ is the dual object to $X$. The coend exists since the category $\mathcal{C}$ is bounded.

We know precisely what the coend of the category $\mathcal{C}$ is, including its structure morphisms as a Hopf algebra object. Moreover, we have a non-degenerate pairing $\omega: C \otimes C \rightarrow \mathbb{1}$, which we can also describe precisely. We know that the existence of a Hopf algebra object implies the existence of a Frobenius algebra object.

The question that concerns me is the following: is it possible to construct the Frobenius algebra object out of this data? If yes, could you please give a reference regarding that construction or something similar to it. I appreciate any comments or help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please give some references for the introduced data, for instance what is (a Hopf algebra object,) a Frobenius object in the given setting, what is "the integral" as an object in the category $\mathcal C$. Are we interested in a specific example, or the construction should be carried in full generality? Is there any theorem which insures that the existence of a Hopf algebra object implies the existence of a Frobenius object? Is there a simple example (vector spaces over some finite field) to have a working setting?!

Comment: Caveat: every *finite-dimensional* Hopf algebra is Frobenius as an algebra, but in the infinite-dimensional setting this cannot be true (a Frobenius algebra is necessarily finite-dimensional)